# How to do testing of HTTP client

Tags: c++, http, testing, web-applications

I am working on an HTTP client. I want to test its behavior for different HTTP Status codes, cookies etc. Is there any website or any other method to do so.

Comment: If you can't find any, it's very easy to create your own server that takes an argument telling it what to return, and return that for every request.

Comment: Actually once i found a website which generated different HTTP status code, but i don't remember the website!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague, but here's an answer to what I think you are asking.

You have a few choices.

First, you can simply get an account cheaply or free.  That's easily enough done, but you won't have a lot of control at the server end in case you need it.

Second, you can set up a local web server and code against that.  You have quite a few choices; please Google IIS or Apache for starters (depending on your platform).  You can even get a full bundle like EasyPHP or WAMP if you want to take advantage of some of the extras they offer.